# random unicode being inserted in my underscore template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, unicode, underscore.js

So there is some unicode being inserted in my template and its causing my iframe src to fail.

The string appears to be `http://sand-dynamic.adpinr.com/social_stream/p_unit/1204042` in the javascript variable, but turns into

```
http://sand-dynamic.adpinr.com%e2%80%ac/social_stream/p_unit/1204042
```

apparently but I'm not sure why. I tried to do this on the variable :

```
obj.URL = unescape(JSON.parse('"' + TL.getURL() + '/social_stream/p_unit/' + obj.id + '"');
```

But it didn't appear to help. My template just calls it like

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="<%= width %>" height="<%= height %>" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" target="_blank" scrolling="no" src="<%= URL %>"></iframe>
```

any thoughts on how I can get rid of that extra unicode? it's preventing me from going to the URL in the browser and it just googles it instead. I'd prefer to have it dynamically remove ANY extra unicode because I don't know how that unicode is getting there in the first place.

Comment: Interesting. If that helps, the character is UTF8-encoded U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%e2%80%ac` is [U+202C](http://www.charbase.com/202c-unicode-pop-directional-formatting). Somehow that character got into your URL variable. That character is invisible, which is why you do not see it when you print out the value of your variable, but see it when the string is URLencoded. You need to edit the string to remove that character. I can't give more info because I don't know where that value is coming from.

If you really want to remove non-ASCII range chars, you could always do something like this:

```
var url = ...
var strippedURL = '';
for (var i = 0, l = url.length; i < l; i++){
  if (url.charCodeAt(i) < 256) strippedURL += url[i];
}
return strippedURL;
```

That is not a good way to solve this though. If you don't know where that char is coming from, then that is just a sign that you have a bug somewhere else in your code that needs to be fixed.